# Ending input data from keyboard by hitting spacebar, not enter key c/c++

Tags: c++, c, input, console, keyboard

I want to input a string by a keyboard, usually end by hitting key enter, but now i want to end by hitting key space
Ex :
Enter your name : Koichen  (hitting enter(`'\n'`) for ending)
Enter your name : Koichen  (hitting space bar(`' '`) for ending)
I use c/c++ for programming
Any hint would be grateful

Comment: You need to catch every keypress inputted and do action when  you encounter Space.

Comment: Not possible with standard C++. You need a special library for your operating system. Besides, I think it's not worth the trouble; if you need such fine-grained control over the console, then you'll soon find out that you need a full GUI anyway.

Comment: The method of doing this depends on the OS you're running on. Are you on windows, linux or other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess what, the standard input is yet not standardized across platforms.

- On unix/linux/mac you need to configure the terminal to [not doing buffer](http://www.unixguide.net/unix/programming/3.2.shtml). then `getc` to poll for input.
- On Windows you call [ReadConsoleInput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/readconsoleinput).

Either way you will need to consolidate the input characters until a space is read.

---

Note that there is no concept of keyboard here, what you read is the `input`, which can for example come from a pipe.

Comment: *"the standard input is yet not standardized across platforms"* - that's a very misleading sentence. Standard input **is** standardised, of course! It's just that keyboards or consoles aren't standardised, and that standard input is an abstract concept while keyboards and consoles are already very concrete things. A computer running a C++ program doesn't need a keyboard or a screen attached to it, but there is still input and output with `std::cin` and `std::cout`.

Comment: It depends on what level of standardization we talking about. The mere exists of platform-dependent way to configure the optional behavior (ie. buffering) I'd say it's not a firm standard.

Comment: Where do you draw the line? Is mouse input also "standard input"?

Comment: I'm not going to ague on this because it's a very blur and subjective opinion. But I'd say cin/cout is standard interface, but the input/output on different platform is not standardized. Consider escape sequence, it will go west on some environment - you call same function, get different results.

Comment: So how to solve this problem ??
I may think about that we can get each letter by `_getch();` and push into a string, but i can not done the same with the unicode because each letter i get to make another letter.
For ex : dd -> đ, uw -> ư, ...

Comment: the easiest way is set terminal as utf8, then you can still push input characters into `std::string`. and space(0x20) can be uniquely identified as multi-byte unicode [does not reuse 0~127 in the sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). and no, if you get `dd` from input it mean `dd` not `đ`, character transform should be done either from terminal or your app post-processing.